# Is it possible to aggregate MongoDB data by "clumps" of timestamps?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregate

Can MongoDB's aggregate pipeline or MapReduce functionality query for many documents, each with timestamps, and group them on timestamps that are within a set range of each other, essentially "clumping" them logically?

For example, if I have 5 documents with the following timestamps:

1. 2017-10-15 11:25:00
2. 2017-10-15 11:28:00
3. 2017-10-15 14:59:00
4. 2017-10-15 15:01:00
5. 2017-10-15 15:06:00
6. 2017-10-15 15:13:00

And my goal is to group them into the following documents:

1. 2017-10-15 11:28:00 (2 events)
2. 2017-10-15 15:06:00 (3 events)
3. 2017-10-15 15:13:00 (1 event)

What I'm logically doing is saying "Group all documents timestamped within 5 minutes of each other".

It's important to note that I'm not just saying "group documents by every five minutes", because if that were the case (assuming the five minute groups started on the hour) documents 3 and 4 would probably not be in the same group.

The other tricky thing is handling documents 3 and 4 in relation to 5. There is more than 5 minutes between documents 3 and 5, but since there is less than 5 minutes between 3 and 4, and between 4 and 5, they'd all get grouped.

(I think it would maybe be OK to get this working without that caveat, where the group had 5 as separate from 3 and 4, because the group starts at 3 and goes for a set "5 minutes", excluding 5. But it would be awesome if the group could be extended like that.)

Comment: Not really in any efficient way. The core problem with calling this an "aggregation" is that you are actually asking to look at one document relative to the "next". This is actually more native to "cursor iteration"  rather than aggregation, since you are basically looking at a "stored state" of what comes before it. That does not exist in the aggregation pipeline, and though you could force it with variables using `mapReduce`, it's "still cursor iteration", but just cursor on the server instead of the client.

Comment: So "grouping at **regular** intervals", is an "aggregation". Looking at documents and "those around it", is actually a cursor iteration. Sure you could stuff all the documents from intervals into "grouped arrays" and then compare them, but that's really just another variation on "cursor iteration" and also not practical for any working set of reasonable size.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, that's what I wast thinking. I'd love to see how best to handle it with MapReduce; I'll play with it.